# Simple form radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

i'm using the simple_form gem and really like its simplicity. However, trying to set to set up a simple radio button is beyond me as I keep getting the following error

**"undefined local variable or method `vegan'"**

1.Here what I have so far

```
 <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :diettype, [[vegan, 'vegan'] ,[vegetarian, 'vegetarian']]%>
```

2.Heres the code I used before simple_form with an update/patch method, which would update and save a users requirement

```
 <%= f.label(:diettype, "Vegan") %>
 <%= f.radio_button(:diettype, "Vegan") %>
 <%= f.label(:diettype, "vegetarian") %>
 <%= f.radio_button(:diettype, "vegetarian")%>
```

3.And here is what I am trying to reproduce

```
<select>
   <option> vegan </option>
   <option> Vegetarian </option>
</select>
```

**NOTE** - vegan and vegetarian are select options that will be stored in the database column of :diettype.

Comment: what is vegetarian and vegan?

Comment: They are radio buttons for my form, that I'd like the user to select

Comment: try: [['vegan','vegan'],['vegetarian', 'vegetarian']]. Or: [[f.vegan,'vegan']] if a database field

Comment: These are options that will be stored in the database column of :diettype as mentioned above

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `controller action`, add this line

```
  def actionname
    @types = ModelName.select(:diettype).distinct
    ..
  end
```

where,

`actionname` is the action which is rendering your view.

`ModelName` is the name of your model which has `diettype` field in it.

In your `view`, replace

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :diettype, [[vegan, 'vegan'] ,[vegetarian, 'vegetarian']]%>
```

with

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :diettype, @types, :diettype, :diettype %>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :diettype, @types, :diettype, :diettype %>
```

The above line means:

Create a collection of radio buttons where,

1st `:diettype` : variable would be set when you select a radio button

`@types` : this collection being passed

2nd `:diettype` : the value that is being selected

3rd `:diettype` : the display text beside the button

**EDIT2**

As you specified that you need a `static collection` and you are not taking any values from database :

Simply add the following line in view, no need to change the controller :

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :name, [['vegan', 'vegan'] ,['vegetarian', 'vegetarian']],:first, :last %>
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line of code? **<%= f.collection_radio_buttons : diettype, @types, :diettype, :diettype %>**

Comment: Do you have any values in `diettype column` of your table? That error would be thrown if your collection is empty, i.e., `@types = nil`. I used `@types` as you said that `select options that will be stored in the database column of :diettype`.  So, they should be present in order to display the list.

Comment: please see my edit. I want to submit **vegan** or **vegetarian** values selected from the select option to **:diettype** coloum

Comment: @samsos ok. so you need static collection with `vegan` and `vegetarian` as values. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hey, when trying to use this solution, I get an error stating that I am trying to call a private method select on my model. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

This is the simplest solution for adding radio buttons with Simple Form that works great for me.

```
 <%= f.input :diettype, as: :radio_buttons, collection: ['Vegan', 'Vegetarian'] %>
```