# Simple Form - Radio Buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Please can someone help me with using Simple Form in my Rails 4 app.

I have a model with an attribute for a 'project_image'. I ask whether a bespoke image should be included and want a yes or no answer.

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :project_image, label: 'Would you like add an image to your project pitch?', :options => [[true, 'Yes'], [false, 'No']], :first, :last, :style =>"display:inline", :default => true %>
```

I keep getting errors with this line of code. They best information coming out of my code editor is that there is a syntax error somewhere (syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>). I've tried removing all the commas, one by one and replacing with => and am not getting anywhere.

I tried following this answer and didn't find any success.
[Simple form radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855709/simple-form-radio-button)

Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Just systematically replacing commas with `=>` doesn't make sense. Your arguments need to match the types described in the documentation for the method. For example, the second argument should be a collection, but yours is an HTML label. You seem to have given the collection as the 3rd argument and labeled it with a has key of `:options` (contrary to examples given in online documentation).

Comment: Well I tried reading the docs before I tried a last ditch effort to find the error. There is something that I can't see. I will go back to the docs and try again, having the benefit of your helpful insight. Thank you.

Comment: If there is anyone that can offer any advice about making sense of this part of the Simple Form documentation, I would really appreciate some help in identifying what this example is actually doing.I managed to get the buttons to show (reordering elements) but lost the label. 

  <input id="user_options_true" name="user[options]" type="radio" value="true" />
<label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_options_true">Yes</label>
<input id="user_options_false" name="user[options]" type="radio" value="false" />
<label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_options_false">No</label>

Comment: Sounds like some progress. Perhaps you could update your question showing the code you've updated and describing the results.